# Dependence of well-orderedness on model's notion of power set

Tags: set-theory

Given that power set is "bigger" in some models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ than others (e.g. $L$ vs forcing extensions of $L$ that add reals), it seems like well-orderedness is in principle dependent on details of the model's notion of power set. For example, it seems it could happen that in some model $M$ there's an $R \subset \omega \times \omega$ that defines a linear ordering of $\omega$ which is not a *well-order* (according to $M$), yet in some other model $M'$ the same $R$ actually ***is*** a well-order simply because $M'$ lacks the subsets of $\omega$ that would fail the "smallest element" criterion (or at least it's not apparent to me that this provably *can't* happen).

On the other hand some orderings, for example an ordering of type $\omega^2$ (in an $\omega$-standard model), definitely seem like "unconditional" well-orders in that they're *always* going to be a well-order (regardless of the details of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ in one model vs. another).

So if we consider linear orders of $\omega$ (subsets of $\omega \times \omega$) in $\omega$-standard models of $\mathsf{ZF}$, it seems that there may be some whose well-orderedness is model-dependent, but also others which are "unconditionally" well-ordered (regardless of details of the model).

My question then is: how can this latter class of "unconditional" well-orders of $\omega$ be described or characterized more precisely (maybe in terms of the hyperarithmetic hierarchy or something like that)?

***Update - Clarifying comparison of ordering relations between models:***
Given orderings of $\omega$ $R$ and $R'$ in $\omega$-models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ $M$ and $M'$ respectively, what I mean by $R$ and $R'$ being "the same" or "equivalent" is that they contain exactly the same ordered pairs of natural numbers.

To be more detailed, consider, for example, in $M$ the finite ordinal $\alpha = 17^M$ (the ordinal that $M$ thinks is the natural number 17); then I say finite ordinal $\alpha'$ (in $M'$) is "equivalent" to $\alpha$ iff $\alpha' = 17^{M'}$ (the ordinal that $M'$ thinks is 17). This doesn't necessarily mean $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ are the same set according to the $=$ operator of the background universe. Similarly, for ordered pairs of finite ordinals $p = \langle a, b \rangle$ in $M$ and $p' = \langle a', b' \rangle$ in $M'$, I say $p$ and $p'$ are "equivalent" if their elements are "equivalent" in the sense just described for finite ordinals ($a \sim a'$ and $b \sim b'$). And finally I say $R$ and $R'$ are the "the same" (or "equivalent") orderings if they contain exactly the same ordered pairs of natural numbers ("same" pairs according to the equivalence notion for pairs just described); again, this doesn't necessarily mean that $R$ and $R'$ are the same set according to the $=$ operator of the background universe.

I realize there may be a technical term (unknown to me) that could express this more concisely, but hopefully my meaning here is clear.

Comment: This question has so many small holes it may as well be a colander. For example, are we talking about Class models of ZF?  transitive models of ZF? well-founded models of ZF? $\omega$-models of ZF? Countable models of ZF? Do all of the models concerned here have the same ordinals? Do they all have, at least the same countable ordinals (that is, any ordinal which is countable in some model, appears in all the models)? Because any of these questions will impact how the answer changes from yes to no (or vice versa).

Comment: I was aiming for maximum generality, didn’t realize it would complicate the answer a lot. If, in addition to the original stipulation of focusing on $\omega$-standard models (same thing as “$\omega$-models”?), one narrows it down to transitive models, does that make the answer reasonably tractable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M\subseteq N$ are two models of $\sf ZF$ with the same ordinals, then they agree on well-orders.

To see this, note that if $R\in M$ is a well-ordering, that means that there is an isomorphism from $R$ to an ordinal $\alpha$ inside $M$. This, in turn, means that this isomorphism is also in $N$, and since $\alpha$ is still an ordinal in $N$, it must mean that $R$ is still well-ordered in $N$.

So, in particular, any two transitive models agree on well-orders. Any two well-founded models "kinda agree" in the sense that we can somehow cheat and make them disagree on what a particular element is coding (e.g. take a permutation of a transitive model moving an ordinal to the real numbers, this defines a well-founded relation which satisfies the axioms of $\sf ZF$ but where some ordinal is not really an ordinal), but this is not the point, and up to their unique transitive collapse, the agreement is very much in place.

Of course, this can easily break down if the two models disagree on the ordinals (or rather, the ordinals of $M$ are not necessarily ordinals in $N$).

Indeed, this is almost trivial, since if $M\models\alpha\in\rm Ord$, but $N$ sees that $\alpha$ is not a real ordinal, then $\alpha$ is a counterexample. If $\alpha$ happened to be countable, and $M$ happened to be an $\omega$-model, then $\alpha$ can be coded by a relation on $\omega$ which is now in both models but only well-founded in one of them.

Finally, if the two models vastly disagree on the ordinals (e.g. we are comparing a model $M$ such that $\omega^M$ is uncountable in $N$, and $N$ which is a transitive model) then the question practically lost its meaning here.

Comment: I realized my question could maybe benefit from clarification re what I mean about comparing ordering relations between different models (added in "Update" to the question above) . To double-check my original supposition: (cont'd...)

Comment: Let $M$ be an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ with $R$ a well-order of $\omega$ of order type $\omega^2$ (concretely: 0 and all positive integers not evenly divisible by 10 (ordered the normal way), followed by multiples of 10 not divisble by 100 (ordered "normally"), and so on). If the "equivalent" ordering $R'$ ("equivalent" in the sense specified in my update) exists in some other $\omega$-model $M'$, then $R'$ must also be a well-order according to $M'$ (regardless of whether $M'$ is transitive or not, regardless of how much "bigger" $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ may be in $M'$, etc.). Correct?

Comment: I don't know why you're reinventing the word and concept of "equality".

Comment: Well, the notion I described there is based on how I assumed one would think about models of theories ($\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ and others) from the perspective of their function as a foundation for the rest of mathematics. From that perspective, I would care about questions like "does the busy beaver function exist in the model?" (for $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ the answer is "no", to my knowledge). But I probably don't care, given models $M$ and $M'$, whether the natural number 17 in $M$ and 17 in $M'$ are actually the *same set* according to the $"="$ operator of the background universe...(cont'd)

Comment: ...Or at least that's how it seems to me. But maybe the way I tried to sort of "formalize" this is awkward. In any case, just one thing I didn't quite understand about this answer, namely in the 3rd paragraph the scenarios (e.g. the "cheat") under which well-founded models might disagree about well-orders.

Comment: Take a permutation of $\omega$, that defines an order isomorphic to the original one, in which, say $5$ is the minimum, rather than $0$. Same thing here, swap around things, so the model is well founded, but the ordinals are not "really" ordinals. If nothing else, this tells you that inclusion is not always meaningful.